# React Native: The development server returned response error code 404

Tags: android, macos, react-native, server, ngrok

I am trying to run a react native app on my computer, using an a Ngrok server. I am using port 8081 on my computer, when i run the command npm start in terminal my server runs on the port, and when i cancel the process in terminal the page cant be reached. So everything seems to be in order there (its not another service running on that port).

When im trying to connect from my phone, using the Viro Media app, i get this error:

[image: Image of the error form my phone]

I have been going through too many google-pages on solutions, but i cant understand whats wrong. I also have been allowing connections to my computer in my security options, turned off the firewall, dubble checked that im in the correct folder etc.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Ok finally managed to solve the problem. I created a new project and made sure i was not using react-native, react-native-cli, typescript and ngrok globally. Re-installed and followed up and every warning i got, and then when i ran npm-start i could connect my phone.